# Can a UK resident enter the UK on a non-EEA passport that is about to expire?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, uk-residents

I have four months left on my US passport and seven on my UK residence permit.

Can I travel to the US for a week (where I am a citizen) and then return home to the UK where I am a resident and own property?

Comment: It does not appear that the UK requires US passports to be valid beyond the date of entry; likewise, UK residence permits are good documentation right until they actually expire.

Comment: Your right to enter the US is unquestionable. I've therefore trimmed the question down to UK reentry.

Comment: Looking at Timatic, "Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to residents of the United Kingdom must be valid on arrival." [and need not be valid any longer than that.]

Comment: @JonathanReez but documents required for entry into the US must also be accepted by the carrier in order to *reach* the US. An airline is not going to board a US citizen for a flight to the US without a valid US passport (or, if applicable, an acceptable substitute such as a trusted traveler program card).

Comment: @phoog his passport isn't expired yet, so the airline doesn't care

Comment: @JonathanReez agreed. I just wanted to note that when traveling internationally, the passport has another role at least aside from entering the country, and the "unquestionable" legal right of entry doesn't necessarily help in the other context.